# How to create a layout with four equally spaced images with text underneath?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I want to show four images as shown in given imaages . each image must be equally far apart from others I have tried a LinearLayout and use it weight property but all in sane.[image]

I have eight icons, four for selected state and four for unselected state. I have tried many ways,

Thanks in Advance.

Image Icons are ..

xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/article_icn"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:scaleType="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/forum_icn"
            android:padding="10dp"
             android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_icn"
            android:padding="10dp"
             android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:scaleType="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Textview" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:scaleType="center" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Textview" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Textview" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Textview" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Screen**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and modified a bit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/icon"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/icon"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/icon"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Assigning `android:weightSum="3"` to container and weight 1 to all images works fine:

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check this layout, works exactly as you want. Just replace the image icons and background.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg" >
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#517398" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/image_agenda"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/image_month"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/image_month"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/image_day"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use weight attrib:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000000"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_chat" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_chat" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_chat" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_chat" />

</LinearLayout>
```

output is like this:

[image]